# html string is not loading for second time after getting response

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview

In my project I'm working in UIWebView. In this I'm converting one HTML file into NSString after getting web service response then I load to the UIWebView it working fine, for the first time it working again I'm hitting the web service it not loading. Below is my code help me thanks in advance

```
//After getting response from web service
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"graph" ofType:@"html"];
htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:[timeArr componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

for first time it loading but the second time it not loading,

I tried `[self.webView reload];`

HTML File

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
                var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
                var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'event' });
                dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
                dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
                dataTable.addRows([ 'stop', new Date(2001, 2, 3,00,00,00), new Date(2001, 2, 3,03,21,02) ],
                                  [ 'drive', new Date(2001, 2, 3,03,21,02), new Date(2001, 2, 3,03,22,25) ],[ 'stop', new Date(2001, 2, 3,03,22,25), new Date(2001, 2, 3,05,27,30) ],[ 'drive', new Date(2001, 2, 3,05,27,30), new Date(2001, 2, 3,05,28,41) ],[ 'stop', new Date(2001, 2, 3,05,28,41), new Date(2001, 2, 3,06,31,11) ],[ 'drive', new Date(2001, 2, 3,06,31,11), new Date(2001, 2, 3,06,31,36) ],[ 'stop', new Date(2001, 2, 3,06,31,36), new Date(2001, 2, 3,06,37,55) ],[ 'drive', new Date(2001, 2, 3,06,37,55), new Date(2001, 2, 3,07,33,15) ],[ 'idle', new Date(2001, 2, 3,07,33,15), new Date(2001, 2, 3,08,03,05) ],[ 'idle', new Date(2001, 2, 3,08,03,05), new Date(2001, 2, 3,08,32,55) ]);

                chart.draw(dataTable);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="timeline" style="height: 280px;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you send your graph.html file?

Comment: i added the html file data

Comment: I want you to send the HTML file

Comment: the above code only i used in the graph.html.

Comment: I ran it.it does not show anything when first time I run the app.

Comment: but i'm getting output